# Identifying a fantasy genre series - magic users drain strength from others

Tags: story-identification

From what I can remember, it has about 6 books in the series, I believe.
It is a fantasy, medieval, magic background.

It revolves around people using a form of magic to boost their strength, agility and looks by taking it from others, essentially linking them while making the victims weak, comatose.

The main protagonist uses the magic forcefully on the kings and lords he conquers, while the hero refuses it but slowly accepts when people does it willingly to boost him.
I believe the hero had an affinity to earth  / nature magic, could be wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: _"The main **protagonist** uses the magic forcefully on the kings and lords he conquers, while the **hero**"_ - so the protagonist isn't a hero? Or did you mean antagonist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like David Farland's Runelord series that beings with "The Sum of All Men"; the hero does have an affinity for nature, and the magic involves "endowments" that do make one stronger at the expense of the other.